# Page factory Design pattern selenium

Tags: selenium

In my application I'm implementing page factory design pattern, I have a webpage with 10 Links which I have written a generic xpath so I can replace the text value alone while performing action. I'm not able to use @findby annotation since it will take only constant values for WebElement. Can you please suggest how to use page factory pattern in the case where we have similar objects in a same/across page to reuse the locators also. Example : Do I need to declare 10 WebElements for those many links which is not a good practice or any other workarounds

Comment: Please include any code you have made to attempt and solve your question so others can help show you where you are going wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I always use list arrays in this scenario.

```
@findBy(xpath = "//a")
List<WebElement> allLinks;
```

You then search/manipulate the array and its elements.

```
for (WebElement link : allLinks)
    if (link.getText().toLowercase(contains("home")) {
        link.click();
        break;
    }
```

disclaimer: air code